# How to test that an object is created by another?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I have an object from class `A` that creates another object from class `B` using an instance method. And I would like to test it's created correctly with the `attribute_to_check` with value `True` in `pytest`

```py
class B:
    def __init__(self, attribute_to_check=None):
        self.attribute_to_check = attribute_to_check or False
    
    def some_method():
        # some actions...

class A:
    def __init__(self, some_attr):
        self.some_attr = some_attr
        ...

    async def create_object_b(self, something_not_relevant):
       ...
       object_b = B(attribute_to_check=True)
       object_b.some_method()
       ...
       return None
```

Edit: the method above does not return `object_b` but rather uses its methods.

And the test would be something like this:

```py
async def test_object_created():
    object_A = A(some_attrs)
    await object_A.create_object_b(something_not_relevant="")
    # How can I access and assert object B is created with attribute_to_check == True?
```

I tried creating a fixture for the object of class `B`, but that wouldn't be testing what I intend which is that the function from class `A` instantiates an object of class `B` with the expected value for the attribute.

Comment: your method `A.create_object_b` is suposed to be create an object of type `B`, and return it, right?

Comment: No, I think that's what's tricky about it. It instantiates an object of class `B` to use its methods. But it's important that I check the actual attribute it's instantiated with in this case. I'll add that to the question, thanks @RafaelDouradoD

Comment: Is `object_b` returned from the method? If not why are you trying to test it?

Comment: You don't return `object_b` from `create_object_b`, so it's gone at when you `return` out of that function. You can't access it outside.

Comment: It's not. I'm trying to test it's instantiated with the `attribute_to_check = True` instead of the default one which is `False`. I'm guessing you mean that I should be testing the behavior it causes instead of the actual instantiation? @rdas

Comment: @danielsto, if that's the case, then I recommend you create a method in `A` that just create this object `B`, than another method that will handle the B methods. Also, by your code, its obvious that `B` was created using `attribute_to_check=True`, there is no need to test it

Comment: Also, in doing `object_b = B(attribute_to_check=True)`, and since you do `self.attribute_to_check = attribute_to_check or False` in the constructor for `B`, the `object_b` _must_ have `attribute_to_check == True`. Note that the `or False` in the assignment to `self.attribute_to_check` is redundant if you simply set the default value to `False` instead of `None`. `X or False` is always `X`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to refactor your method `create_object_b` to just create the b object (consistence with method name and method behavior). This way you can check if B was created with the attributes you want

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, attribute_to_check=None):
        self.attribute_to_check = attribute_to_check or False

    def some_method():
        # some actions...

class A:
    def __init__(self, some_attr):
        self.some_attr = some_attr
        ...

    async def create_object_b(self, something_not_relevant) -> B:
        ...
        object_b = B(attribute_to_check=True)
        ...
        return object_b

    async def make something_with_b(self, object_b: B):
        b.some_method()
```

test class

```
async def test_object_created():
    object_A = A(some_attrs)
    object_b = await object_A.create_object_b(something_not_relevant="")

    assert object_b.some_attribute == True
```